Typescript error d3 RGBColor not having r, g, b properties
I'm trying to add opacity on colors using a d3 colorscale with diverging scheme.
Here's what I got so far :
const data = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3];
const colorScale = d3.scaleDiverging(d3.interpolateRdBu).domain([-3, 0, 3]);
const fooColor = colorScale(2); // returns rgb(58, 132, 187)

Now if I want to add opacity to that color, I need to retrieve r,g,b values and recreate some rgba string like that :
const rgbColor = d3.color(fooColor);
const rgbaColor = "rgba(" + rgbColor?.r + "," + rgbColor?.g + "," + rgbColor?.b + "," + 0.7 + ")";

This gives some typescript error : Property 'r' does not exist on type 'RGBColor | HSLColor'.. Same for g and b properties. Yet, if I print the rgbColor object, it does have r, g, b and opacity properties.
Anyone having the same error ?
By the way, if someone knows a way to get d3 scheme working with opacity without having to make such hack, please share your solution :)

Why is using d3.color a hack?  You are using it as intended.  Although, I'd probably code it as  const fooColor = d3.color(colorScale(2)); fooColor.opacity = 0.7; const rgbColor = fooColor.toString()

@Mark Actually, I said hack because of the color splitting + rgba string re-creation thing. I hoped there was a way to specify some opacity directly when calling the color scheme. But I'm glad my approach looks fine to you :)
Anyway, I think that opacity is an access-only property and can't be set like this, am I right ?

Added an answer below for completeness sake.  I tested it in typescript without issue.  Although, as Muhammad points out in his answer, typescript can sometimes be quite fickle.

You're encountering this TypeScript error because the d3.color(fooColor) function can return either an RGBColor or an HSLColor, and TypeScript cannot guarantee that r, g, and b properties exist on both types. However, these properties only exist on RGBColor. To avoid the error, you can safely cast the color to RGBColor like this:
const rgbColor = d3.color(fooColor) as d3.RGBColor;
const rgbaColor = `rgba(${rgbColor.r}, ${rgbColor.g}, ${rgbColor.b}, 0.7)`;


Thank you, I tried to find types definition but failed, and I didn't understand this type distinction between RGBColor and HSLColor ! Can you please provide a link to those RGBColor type definition ? index.d.ts file from DefinitelyTyped was not very helpful.

The type definitions for RGBColor and HSLColor can be tricky to find. They are part of the @types/d3-color package. You can view them here:
RGBColor
HSLColor
To clarify, RGBColor has r, g, b, and opacity properties, while HSLColor has h, s, l, and opacity. Since TypeScript can’t distinguish between these two, casting to RGBColor is necessary when you need r, g, and b.
Let me know if you have any further questions!

I think you tried to insert a link to some online resources but they do not show up, can you provide URLs as raw text ? Thanks again for your help !

I don't believe using d3.color is hacky at all.  The scale interpolator returns a string for ease of use and d3.color can convert that string into a richer object for further manipulation.  The one thing I would avoid in your example code is the string manipulation.  I would code it like this:
import * as d3 from 'd3';

const data = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3];
const colorScale = d3.scaleDiverging(d3.interpolateRdBu).domain([-3, 0, 3]);
const fooColor = d3.color(colorScale(2)); 
fooColor.opacity = 0.7; 
const rgbaColor = fooColor.toString();
console.log(rgbaColor); 

